# GSAP Scrolltrigger Parallax Sections

Tags: image, animation, vuejs2, gsap

I'm kind of newbie and and I'm starting to be very fascinated by GSAP animations...
I found this with the code and everything: https://codepen.io/GreenSock/pen/QWjjYEw.

My problem is that in this animation I have some random pictures, but I want to use some local images that I have instead. Any suggestion of what to change?
I'm using Vue 2 and I put already the JS in the mounted :)

Thanks in advance!

I know that I should change this part but I don't know how

```
  section.bg.style.backgroundImage = `url(https://picsum.photos/1600/800?random=${i})`;
```

I tried to duplicate this

```
part:section.bg = section.querySelector(".bg");
```

with:

```
section.bg = section.querySelector(".bg");
section.bg = section.querySelector(".bg2")
section.bg = section.querySelector(".bg3");
```

and then here :

```
section.bg.style.backgroundImage = "url('myImagePath')";
section.bg2.style.backgroundImage = "url('myImagePath')";
section.bg3.style.backgroundImage = "url('myImagePath')";
```

Nothing happens...if I put the imagepath inline style on the html I lose the animation.

Answer (score 0):

First, your Q not related to vue.
Next inspect your code (For errors -- your main mistake `section.bg` is item inside a forEach loop - the path should be related to each iteration).

One way (DRY) to change the images from random images is to get the `data-attribute` of each `bg` item inside the `forEach` "section" loop.

[image]

One way to solve this.

Change the path from random path:

```
  section.bg.style.backgroundImage = `url(https://picsum.photos/1600/800?random=${i})`;
```

To specific one for `each` iteration:

```
  /*#### NEW CODE ####*/
  let image_path = section.bg.dataset.image;
  // Get images path from data attribute
  section.bg.style.backgroundImage = `url(${image_path})`;
```

Read more:

- **Use_data_attributes:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes
- **GSAP UtilityMethods:** https://greensock.com/docs/v3/GSAP/UtilityMethods/toArray()
- **querySelector**: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector